# MongoDB query to replace NULL values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently working with a MongoDB database and I have fields that have a value of NULL is there a way to run a query that will replace these NULL fields with a value of "Missing" instead?
An example of the document is:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "Users" : [
                {
                        "name" : "John Davies",
                        "age" : null,
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Edward Jones",
                        "age" : null,
                        "place_of_birth" : null
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Daniel Rhys",
                        "age" : NumberLong(63),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                },
                {
                        "name" : null,
                        "age" : NumberLong(61),
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "John Davies ",
                        "age" : null,
                        "place_of_birth" : "Cardigan"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Is this a one-time activity?

Comment: Yes, I would only want to do this once

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/dsI5G6zfbLr

Use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

```
db.collection.update(
    {},
    { $set: { "Users.$[u].age": "missing" } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "u.age": null } ], multi: true}
)
```

---

Combine multiple queries into 1 using [db.collection.bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

```
db.collection.bulkWrite( [
   { updateMany :
      {
         "filter": {},
         "update": { $set: { "Users.$[u].age": "missing" } },
         "arrayFilters": [ { "u.age": null } ],
      }
   },
   { updateMany :
      {
         "filter": {},
         "update": { $set: { "Users.$[u].name": "missing" } },
         "arrayFilters": [ { "u.name": null } ],
      }
   },
   { updateMany :
      {
         "filter": {},
         "update": { $set: { "Users.$[u].place_of_birth": "missing" } },
         "arrayFilters": [ { "u.place_of_birth": null } ],
      }
   }
] )
```

---

#### Update for MongoDB Version 3.2+

```
while (db.collection.find({$or:[{"Users.age":null},{"Users.name":null},{"Users.place_of_birth":null}]}).count()) {
   db.collection.bulkWrite( [
       { updateMany :
          {
             "filter": { "Users.age": null },
             "update": { $set: { "Users.$.age": "missing" } }
           }
       },
       { updateMany :
          {
             "filter": { "Users.name": null },
             "update": { $set: { "Users.$.name": "missing" } },
          }
       },
       { updateMany :
          {
             "filter": { "Users.place_of_birth": null },
             "update": { $set: { "Users.$.place_of_birth": "missing" } },
          }
       }
    ] )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) starting from MongoDB 4.2,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `Users` array
- `$objectToArray` to convert current object in `$map` to array key-value pair
- `$map` to iterate loop of above converted array
- `$ifNull` to check if value is null then replace `Missing` otherwise remain same
- `$arrayToObject` convert above key-value array to object format

```
db.collection.update({},
  [{
    $set: {
      Users: {
        $map: {
          input: "$Users",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: {
              $map: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$$this" },
                in: {
                  k: "$$this.k",
                  v: { $ifNull: ["$$this.v", "Missing"] }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xXvFP4B5N9a)

**MongoDB version 3.2 or above:**

- set default value for replacement in variable `nullReplace`
- `find()` query to get all documents from your collection and loop through forEach
- for loop of user object and check condition if value is null then replace `nullReplace` variable
- return user oibject
- `updateOne()` to update updated `Users` array in your collection

```
var nullReplace = "Missing";
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    var Users = doc.Users.map(function(u) {
        for (var u in userObj) {
            if (userObj[u] === null) userObj[u] = nullReplace;
        }
        return userObj;
    })
    db.collection.updateOne({ _id: doc._id }, { $set: { Users: Users } });
});
```

Comment: I am using server version is MongoDB server version: 3.2 is there a way of doing this for that particular version?

Comment: @PearDrop that is the only way in 3.2 i have added at last in answer.